# Trying to sit two forms next to eachother in Bootstrap. Any ideas how to?

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to sit two forms next to eachother in Bootstrap. Any ideas how to?

Basically, I just have too much white space to the right hand side and I'd like to just place both keycode & zipcode forms on the same line so it visually looks pleasing.

http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/cart.aspx

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="cartoptionbox">
      <div class="control-group">
       <div class="controls">
        <form class="form-horizontal form-inline" method="post" id="Keycode">
                <input type="hidden" name="formName" value="dmiformCouponKeycodeHandler">
                <input type="hidden" name="pageURL" value="[[DMI:Expression value='Core.GetCurrentPageName()' ]][[/DMI:Expression]]"> 
                <h4 class="heading4"> Enter source code for discounted pricing.</h4>
                <fieldset>
                        <label class="label" for="keycode" title="Keycode">
                            Source Code: 
                        </label>
                            <input type="text" id="keycode" name="keycode" />
                            <input id="cart-keycode-apply" type="submit" class="btn btn-orange" value="Apply" />
                </fieldset>
        </form>

        <form class="form-horizontal form-inline" id="ShipEstimate">
          <h4 class="heading4"> Enter your Zip Code to get a shipping estimate.</h4>
          <fieldset>
                <label class="label" for="PostalCode_SHIP" title="Zip">
                            Zip Code:
                        </label>
                      <input type="text" id="PostalCode_SHIP" value="" name="PostalCode_SHIP" OnChange='populateCartTotalInCartPage();' minlength="5" />
                      <input type="hidden" id="COUNTRY_SHIP" name="COUNTRY_SHIP" value="US" />
                <input type="button" OnClick="populateCartTotalInCartPage();toggleTable();" value="Get Quotes" class="btn btn-orange">
          </fieldset>
        </form>

        <script>
          $("#ShipEstimate").validate();
        </script>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap, you want to take a look at the Grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid.

Here's a basic idea to get things rolling:

```
<div class="cartoptionbox">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="key code">Source Code</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="keycode" name="keycode">
                    <input id="cart-keycode-apply" type="submit" class="btn btn-orange" value="Apply">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="PostalCode_SHIP">Zip Code:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="PostalCode_SHIP" value="" name="PostalCode_SHIP" onchange="populateCartTotalInCartPage();" minlength="5">
                    <input type="button" onclick="populateCartTotalInCartPage();toggleTable();" value="Get Quotes" class="btn btn-orange">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind that the magic number is "12", so in the example above the columns would be equally weighted. Otherwise, you could do a 1/3 or 3/1 split using the `.span3` and `.span9` classes. You have plenty of options along with being able to offset columns as well.

**Update**
I've updated the example above to show you a little more within the context of your code. I did not include all of it.

**Update #2**
Take a look at the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Yp3ve/1/

Comment: I just gave this a go and...woah. http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/cart.aspx

Looks like it not only didn't put them on the same line, but somehow jacked up the optionbox that contains them.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything. Where on the page is this code supposed to show up?

Comment: The "Enter source code" and "Enter your zip" forms.

You may have to add an item to your cart.

Comment: Updated the example...you have several issues going on with your HTML structure. Just for starters...you have a form element inside of another form element. You should work to clean the structure up first. Then, you should be able to lay in the CSS with little pain.

Comment: http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/cart.aspx

That seemed to help a bit, but not placing them on the same line yet though. Awesome on being so specific with the code though, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Right, you still have issues with your HTML structure, and I would highly recommend cleaning those issues up before you tackle your CSS issues. You have a padding/margin type issue which is preventing the `.span6` elements from floating side by side the way they should. You could spend hours trying to hack your CSS to make it line up, but your solution will break the minute you (or someone else) cleans up your structural issues. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the each form in a container, like a `span6` div or something.